# Django: how to make STATIC_URL empty?

Tags: python, django

Yep, I want it to work like in Flask framework - there I could set parameters like this:

`static_folder=os.getcwd()+"/static/", static_url_path=""`

and all the files that lies in `./static/files/blabla.bla` would be accessible by `mysite.com/files/blabla.bla` address. I really don't want to add `static` after `mysite.com`.

But if I set `STATIC_URL = '/'` in Django then I could get my static files by this address, but suddenly I could not fetch my pages that described in `urls.py`.

Comment: Django isn't Flask. If you want to leverage STATIC_URL or MEDIA_URL in your templates or otherwise, you'll need to specify those settings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not supported out of the box. Off the top of my head, one way to do it would be with a special 404 handler that, having failed to match against any of the defined URLs, treats the request as a request for a static resource. This would be reasonably easy to do in the development environment but significantly more difficult when nginx, Apache, and/or gunicorn get involved.

In other words, don't do this. Nest your statics (or put them on a different sub domain) but don't mix the URL hierarchy in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to accomplish with Nginx using try_files. Using the pseudo-settings below will make Nginx try to find a static file first, and if it fails then execution is passed to your django app.

```
server {
  ...
  root /some/path/to/assets/;
  try_files $uri @django;

  location @django {
    ...
    proxy_pass  http://unix:/some/path/to/server.sock;
  }
}
```

Example: The file `/some/path/to/assets/myfile.ext` will be available as `http://mydomain/myfile.ext`

Comment: This won't work with the built-in runserver so you will either have to hard-code the files in your urls.py or use Nginx on your local machine as well (but run the Django app with DEBUG=True). Tough luck if you develop on Windows, easy to set up if you are on unix or osx.

Comment: I actually replaced Win7 with Xubuntu on my primary laptop to get a better development environment for Django. It solves this particular problem, plus things like gevent, celery and such things are much easier to get working reliably on unix. Plus my development environment now looks a lot more like my deployment environment which I find really useful.